# Why is rolling.aggregate with several functions taking longer than looping through each one?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, rolling-computation

I would like to use groupby.pandas.rolling.aggregate(func) where func is a list of functions, but I am finding this is much slower than looping through each function separately and concatenating the results.

Wanted to check if this expected behaviour or if I am doing something wrong?

And curious to know why this is for education.

In the below code, you will see I have tried 2 versions:

- Vs1: pass the functions as a list to the aggregate function
- Vs2: loop through the list and pass each function to the aggregate function and concat the results at the end

I find Vs2 is significantly faster than Vs1. On my PC I get **Vs1 @ 10.25 secs and Vs2 @ 0.75 secs**

```py
import datetime
import time

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    1,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [["a", "b", "c"], list(range(10000))], names=["letter", "int"]
    ),
    columns=range(100),
)
df_g = df.groupby(["letter"])

func_list = ["sum", "count", "mean", "std"]

# Vs 1 - pass functions as a list
start_time = time.time()
res_df_list = df_g.rolling(100, min_periods=1).aggregate(func_list)
end_time = time.time()
time_lapsed = end_time - start_time
print(f"Vs1: {str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_lapsed))}")

# Vs 2 - loop through each function
start_time = time.time()
res_list = []
for func in func_list:
    res = df_g.rolling(100, min_periods=1).aggregate(func)
    res.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([res.columns.to_list(), [func]])
    res_list.append(res)
res_df_loop = pd.concat(res_list, axis=1)
end_time = time.time()
time_lapsed = end_time - start_time
print(f"Vs2: {str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_lapsed))}")
```

Comment: is this indent correct?  In Vs2, you have `res_list.append(res)` outside of for loop. res is overwritten and the last result is appended only.

Comment: @Emma, thanks - have amended the indent. Code now in line with what I intended